# two dimensional array and pointer arithmetic

Tags: pointers, math, multidimensional-array

I am trying to copy a 2 dimensional array to another 2 dimensional array.  Since the name (srcAry) is the address of the first element of the source array, I have been able to print out all the values in the source  array using pointer arithmetic in a for loop.  I am using the number of rows times the number of columns as the condition to stop looping.  If I try to assign the values to the new array using this method I get an error message (error: assignment to expression with array type).   Is this possible to do this or am I limited to using two nested for loops with indexes?
...

```
void copyAry(double *pAry, int numRows, int numCols)
{
    double newAry[numRows][numCols];
    int end = numRows * numCols;
    int ctr = 0;

    for( ; ctr < end; ctr++)

  //  printf("*(pAry + %d) = %.1f\n", ctr, *(pAry + ctr));  //this works fine 
     {
       *(newAry + ctr) = *(pAry + ctr);   //this is where I receive error
     }
    return;
}
```

...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to allocate memory for `newAry` with `new, malloc` or other function , or defining `double newAry[numRows][numCols];` makes allocation automatically in your language?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the type of `newAry + ctr` is not `double*` as your code assumes, but rather `double*[numCols]` i.e. a pointer to an array of `numCols` elements. Which also means that you would advance not one element at a time, but `numCols`.

Usually you would use `memcpy` for this kind of low level data copying. Barring that, you might start with `double* pNewAry = &newAry[0][0]` or some such in order to test the 2d array as a linear sequence of doubles.